# Spin in 3d orbitals of 2 irons

Tags: quantum-spin, orbitals

Which technique/method/theory must I use in order to calculate/see what happens at the spin of 3d orbitals when two atoms of Iron come close?

Comment: A good starting point would be LCAO theory.

Comment: Thank you very much! I already have a tight-binding code build in my pc. If I'm not mistaken, tight-binding with LCAO are very close as concepts (if not the same). So, do you think that there is any chance i can calculate this with the tight-binding method?
*My  code package is PythTB in Python language.